# Java Program not printing out all the values I specified

Tags: java, debugging, testing, test-class

So in my homework for a Java course we had to modify a class and then write a tester class in Jgrasp, my tester class looks like this

```
public class BankAccountTester {
   public static void main(String[]args){
      BankAccount account = new BankAccount(1000);
      account.setFreeTrans(5);
      account.setTransFee(2);
      account.deposit(1000);
      account.withdraw(500);
      account.withdraw(400);
      account.deposit(200);
      System.out.println(account.getBalance());
      System.out.println("expected: 1300");
      account.monthlyCharge();
      System.out.println(account.getBalance());
      System.out.println("expected: 1300");
      account.deposit(1000);
      account.withdraw(500);
      account.withdraw(400);
      account.deposit(500);
      System.out.println(account.getBalance());
      System.out.println("expected: 1900");
      account.monthlyCharge();
      System.out.println(account.getBalance());
      System.out.println("expected: 1900");
      account.deposit(1000);
      account.withdraw(500);
      account.withdraw(400);
      account.deposit(200);
      account.deposit(500);
      account.withdraw(1000);
      System.out.println(account.getBalance());
      System.out.println("expected 1700");
      account.monthlyCharge();
      System.out.println(account.getBalance());
      System.out.println("expected 1698");
      account.deposit(1000);
      account.withdraw(500);
      account.withdraw(400);
      account.deposit(200);
      account.deposit(500);
      account.withdraw(1000);
      account.deposit(100);
      System.out.println(account.getBalance());
      System.out.println("expected 1598");
      account.monthlyCharge();
      System.out.println(account.getBalance());
      System.out.println("expected 1594");
      }
  }
```

So The Issues I having is that it is not printing out all the values I programed it to print out, it should print out somthing that looks like this:

```
1300
expected: 1300
1300
expected 1300
1900
expected 1900
1900
expected 1900
1700
expected 1700
1698 
expected 1698
1598
expected 1598
1594
expected 1594
```

but instead all I am getting is this:

```
1300.0
expected: 1300
1300.0
expected: 1300
1900.0
expected: 1900
1900.0
expected: 1900
```

does anybody know what this is as I cannot figure out a reason it would do this. note this testing is done the the workbench for JGrasp.
Thanks

Comment: Add your  BankAccount class here

Comment: Seems like Balance is a double or float in your BankAccount class.

Comment: Are you questioning the `.0`, or are you asking why it stops after 4 values?

Comment: I am asking why it stops after 4 values